# Creating the loop using GCD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

So here is what I've got:

```
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1*NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
                bool ready = some_function();
                if( ready ) {                    
                   do_smth_here()
                } else {
                   //invoke this block one more time after 0.1 sec
                }
            });
```

The problem is how can I get the reference to the current block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of jumping through the hoops shown above, I typically declare an instance method that I can call that, internally, takes care of the retriggers as necessary.   That way, any given block is one-shot, but the re-trigger creates a new block.

As long as the block creation isn't terribly expensive -- which it won't be if the state is coming from whatever encapsulates the instance method -- it is efficient enough and a heck of a lot simpler.

```
- (void) retriggerMethod
{
     ... do stuff here, assuming you want to do it on first invocation ...
     dispatch_after( ..., ^{
         [self retriggerMethod];
     });
}
```

You can restructure it as needed.  And you can easily add a BOOL instance variable if you want to protect against simultaneous retriggers, etc...

This also provides a convenient hook for canceling;  just add a BOOL to the instance that indicates whether the next invocation should really do anything and re-schedule.

Comment: It looks like you use GCD loop like this a lot. I wonder what's the advantages of using it rather than setting a NSTimer?

Comment: @Gon Personal preference, really, but there are some differences.   `dispatch_*()` lets you tightly control the queue, for example.  As I am lazy, I also really like the snippets pasted in by Xcode's code completion. :)

Answer (score 3):

Jeffrey Thomas's answer is close, but under ARC, it leaks the block, and without ARC, it crashes.

Without ARC, a `__block` variable doesn't retain what it references.  Blocks are created on the stack.  So the `callback` variable points to a block on the stack.  When you pass `callback` to `dispatch_after` the first time (outside of the block), `dispatch_after` successfully makes a copy of the block on the heap.  But when that copy is invoked, and passes `callback` to `dispatch_after` again, `callback` is a dangling pointer (to the now-destroyed block on the stack), and `dispatch_after` will (usually) crash.

With ARC, a `__block` variable of block type (like `callback`) *automatically* copies the block to the heap.  So you don't get the crash.  But with ARC, a `__block` variable retains the object (or block) it references.  This results in a retain cycle: the block references itself.  Xcode will show you a warning on the recursive `dispatch_after` call: “Capturing 'callback' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle”.

To fix these problems, you can copy the block explicitly (to move it from the stack to the heap under MRC) and set `callback` to nil (under ARC) or release it (under MRC) to prevent leaking it:

```
    __block void (^callback)() = [^{
        if(stop_) {
            NSLog(@"all done");
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
            callback = nil; // break retain cycle
#else
            [callback release];
#endif
        } else {
            NSLog(@"still going");
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1*NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), callback);
        }
    } copy];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1*NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), callback);
```

Obviously you can drop the `#if` and just use the branch appropriate for your memory management.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code your looking for:

```
__block void (^callback)();
callback = ^{
    bool ready = some_function();
    if( ready ) {
        do_smth_here()
    } else {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1*NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), callback);
    }
};

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1*NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), callback);
```

Thanks to [^ Blocks Tips & Tricks](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/)

Comment: @robmayoff Leak? I don't see it. There is no retain cycle here. `callback` gets automatically retained by `dispatch_after()` and automatically released when the block completes. All the retains and releases cancel out. I don't doubt that there could be some defect in the implementation of blocks that would hold onto an extra reference, but I would have to see it in an analyzer.

Comment: See my answer.  BTW, I tested that your solution crashes (under MRC) and leaks (under ARC) using malloc history logging.

Comment: @robmayoff What can I say? The compiler and runtime are the ultimate judge. Good solution.